# Echo line number from gnu makefile target?

Tags: makefile

I have a complex Makefile and would like to make it easier to see which targets are being built.  The built-in debug options have proven to yield way too much uninteresting info.  Using the $(warning) function, I can log the line number I am on just fine.

```
myTarget: somePrereq1 somePrereq2
   $(warning Building this $@)
```

However, if I put this after the prerequisites/files it will not be echoed/printed until all the prerequisites are done.  It would be more intuitive for me to see them in the order they are referenced, meaning starting with "all".  If I put this same warning line in the prerequisites as below, the $@ character is not populated.

```
myTarget: $(warning Building this $@) somePrereq1 somePrereq2
```

If I could get the line number and pass it to a macro or function, then I could get the order I want.  However I see no way to get the line number after much Googling and Duckducking.  Is there a way I have missed?

Comment: You could take the built-in rules (output from `make -pn`, or `makefile -f /dev/null -p`) and then edit them so that each action (recipe) starts with your warning message, save the result in file `built-in-make-rules`, and then use `make -r -f built-in-make-rules -f makefile …` and you'd get the result you want.  It's kinda hard work, though.

Comment: Have you tried stripping out the unnecessary debug info with `-R`?

Comment: Since a GNU makefile can `include` other makefiles (similarly to the C preprocessor) and since multi-line variables and functions can be user-defined, it isn't obvious what "the line number" means.